# Rails Runner not working on Heroku Scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a `rails runner` command that is not working on `Heroku Scheduler`.

My Rails app has a standalone Ruby script that rune fine as a standalone script in my dev environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 

require 'aws-sdk'

#provide AWS credentials
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  access_key_id: 'my_key',
  secret_access_key: 'my_secret_key'
)

#download files from S3
s3.bucket('my_bucket').object('path/in/s3/test.csv').get(response_target: 'lib/assets/data/test.csv')
```

In dev, I can run it via `cron` by using the `whenever` gem as well as running it from the console using the `load` command. But it will not run using `Heroku Scheduler`. I have tried many different tasks in scheduler:

```
rails runner "lib/assets/ruby/s3download.rb" --a MY_APP
rails runner "lib/assets/ruby/s3download.rb" -a MY_APP
rails runner "lib/assets/ruby/s3download.rb" --app MY_APP
rails runner "lib/assets/ruby/s3download.rb" -app MY_APP
rails runner "lib/assets/ruby/s3download.rb"
```

I keep getting the same output from `heroku logs --ps scheduler`:

```
015-05-21T03:02:59.499850+00:00 heroku[scheduler.3070]: State changed from starting to up
2015-05-21T03:03:02.735002+00:00 heroku[scheduler.3942]: State changed from up to complete
2015-05-21T03:03:02.722488+00:00 heroku[scheduler.3942]: Process exited with status 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but as it is just Ruby code, why not using a rake task instead of a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

Simply tell the scheduler to run "lib/assets/ruby/s3download.rb". You don't need to use `rails runner`. The scheduler can run the standalone script.

Comment: probably need to do `ruby lib/assets/ruby/s3download.rb` -- Difference being invoking ruby with a filepath argument, vs executing a script directly.